# How to shift a cursor from one editText to another editText automatically with database validation?

Tags: android

How to shift my cursor from one editText to another editText automatically?The data which i enter in first edit text(eg.bb) should get validate to database(bb) then move to next editText automatically.

Comment: please post some code to help understand what you want to do. Also, you seem to be asking two things at the same time: how to jump to another editText, and how to do something after a validation happens with the DB.

Comment: if(your condition){}

Comment: Suppose , if i store xyz in DB and when i enter xyz in first editText it should move to the next editText automatically @Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve in this ver manner.

```
if(your condition)
{
next_edittext.requestFocu();
};
```

Hope this helps!!!